# How to close a Window when the value of a specific variable is changed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm opening `loadingWindow` via `window1`. I also have an asynchronous thread running in `window1` (parent window) which will change a specific variable's value at some point. When the value is changed I want to close the `loadingWindow`(child window).

The user clicks on the **Browse** button and selects a file, as soon as the Open Dialog is closed the program will start to import the file asynchronously without the user knowing of it. When the user clicks **Next**, some parts of the file is already loaded and the `loadingWin` will be displayed. When the loading is complete it needs to be closed.

```
    private void E2KNext_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingWin = new LoadingWindow();
        loadingWin.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void E2KBrowse_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            worker.DoWork += WorkerDoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();   
    }

    private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        // Some operations will be done here, when it is finished, 
        // the loadingWindow will be closed

        loadingWin.Close();
    }
```

Comment: yourChildWindow.Close() dint work?

Comment: @Sajeetharan No unfortunately, it didn't.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @Sajeetharan I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't close the window from a `DoWork` handler, because that event is fired on a background thread.  Add a handler for `RunWorkerCompleted` and close the window there instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had missed this.